# Doing End to End Testing on the Admin side with Rails and Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, cucumber, protractor

I'm writing a Protractor test and right now it is as simple as:

```
describe("admin page", function() {
  it("will display the admin page", function() {
    browser.get('/admin');
  })
});
```

But the problem that I'm encounting is that my application is redirecting me to the login form as it should. Administration log in/log out is handled via Ruby on Rails and currently receives testing via RSpec and Cucumber.

I've gone an written up some AngularJS for this side and I'm trying to add the tests for it.

Key Question: Is there anyway to get Rails/Cucumber working together with Angular/Protractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to jump from Rails+Cucumber browser session to a protractor one.

To achieve that you would need to attach protractor to that running selenium instance and there is in fact a [selenium issue regarding this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18#c48) that was closed as "not feasible" 2 months ago, so don't count on it.

Your best bet is to write protractor scripts to login as an Admin, is not that much work, really ;)